# MySqlException thrown when applying EF Core migration on MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I'm currenty working on a new .net core 3.0 web application that relies on a MySQL 8.0 db. When I create the first migration, not nullable date columns are set this way:

```
  CreationDateTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"),
  LastModDateTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"),
```

which would be ok for SQLServer but it leads to the exception when the migration is applied to MySql as GetDate() function is not existing in MySql. I'd like my migrations to be MySql-compliant. Thanks in advance.

In my Startup class this is how I configured the db context

```
  services.AddDbContext<ZeroContext>(options => options.UseMySql(conStr, mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 18), ServerType.MySql))));
```

Comment: What MySql EF provider are you using? official, pomelo etc? it looks like when you are creating the migration the wrong provider is being used.

Comment: I'm using Pomelo. I can't see how a wrong provider is used since pomelo is the only one installed in my project. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer was previously used but I removed it. Moreover, as reported in the second code snippet, UseMySql is used when adding the DbContext.

Comment: do you have anything custom in your `OnModelCreating` to set this up? also - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14705 it might just be a deficiency in pomelo?